# Data manipulation per group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataset structured like this:

```
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5], 'period':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,4], 'dsti':[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.2]})
>>>dat
   id  period  dsti
0   1       1   0.1
1   1       2   0.2
2   1       3   0.5
3   2       1   0.2
4   3       2   0.3
5   4       1   0.3
6   5       2   0.4
7   5       4   0.2
```

I would like to group this table by the `ndg` variable and remove all the observations that have only one entry. Moreover, for each of the customers I need to calculate the difference of `dsti` between periods divided by the amount of months: `dsti2 = (dsti_period_n - dsti_period_(n-1))/(period_n - period_(n-1))`. E.g. for customer number 5 the new variable should be (0.2-0.4)/(4-2).

The final dataset should look like:

```
    id  period  dsti dsti2
0    1       1   0.1  0.1
1    1       2   0.2  0.3
2    5       2   0.4 -0.1
```

Any ideas how to do this rather puzzling transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter out unique rows by id
dat = dat[dat['id'].duplicated(keep=False)].copy()
#get difference per id
df = dat.groupby('id').diff(-1)
#division for new column, df is assigned to dat, because same index in both
dat['dsti2'] = df['dsti'].div(df['period'])
#remove missing rows by dsti2 column
dat = dat.dropna(subset=['dsti2'])
print (dat)
   id  period  dsti  dsti2
0   1       1   0.1    0.1
1   1       2   0.2    0.3
6   5       2   0.4   -0.1
```